# How to view data based on values ​from database ci3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a recapitulation of absent data, which I display using a table in CI. The problem that occurs to me is that the data that appears in the table is not in date order.

[image]

I want to make a report like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuG3Y.png)

The absence data does not match based on the date data above the table

How to display the data according to the date data that I called from the database?

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td>Nip</td>
        <td>Nama Lengkap</td>
         <?php
        foreach ($tampiltgl as $data) :?> 
          <td>
              <?php echo $data['waktu']; ?>
      </td>
         <?php endforeach; ?>  
</thead>
  
<tbody>
     <?php
    $no=1; 
    foreach ($tampil as $data) :?>
      
         <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['nip']; ?> </td>
              
            <td>
                <?php echo $data['nm_lengkap']; ?> 
            </td>
          
            <?php
            
             date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
             $timestamp = date('m');
             $opd=$this->session->userdata('opd');
             $tgl=$this->db->query ("SELECT DISTINCT waktu FROM absen_pagi where opd='$opd'AND MONTH(waktu) ='$timestamp'")->result_array();
        
             $absen = $this->db->query ("SELECT DISTINCT waktu, status from absen_pagi where nip='".$data['nip']."' AND opd='$opd' AND  MONTH(waktu) ='$timestamp'")->result_array();
             
            
             foreach ($absen as $key) :?>

           <td><?php echo $key['status']; ?>  </td>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: recapitulation of absent data means?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? There's no `ORDER BY` in your query. Also, be warned that the queries are widely open for SQL injection - please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Also please see: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td>Nip</td>
        <td>Nama Lengkap</td>
         <?php
        foreach ($tampiltgl as $data) :?> 
          <td>
              <?php echo $data['waktu']; ?>
      </td>
         <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </tr>
</thead>
  
<tbody>
     <?php
    $no=1; 
    foreach ($tampil as $data) :?>
      
         <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['nip']; ?> </td>
              
            <td>
                <?php echo $data['nm_lengkap']; ?> 
            </td>
          
            <?php
            
             date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
             $timestamp = date('m');
             $opd=$this->session->userdata('opd');
             $tgl=$this->db->query ("SELECT DISTINCT waktu FROM absen_pagi where opd='$opd'AND MONTH(waktu) ='$timestamp'")->result_array();
        
             $absen = $this->db->query ("SELECT DISTINCT waktu, status from absen_pagi where nip='".$data['nip']."' AND opd='$opd' AND  MONTH(waktu) ='$timestamp'")->result_array();
             
            foreach ($tampiltgl as $tampiltgldata) {
                $celldata = '';
                foreach ($absen as $key) {
                    if ($tampiltgldata['waktu'] == $key['waktu']) {
                        $celldata = $key['status'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                echo "<td>$celldata</td>";
            } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When displaying the `$absen` data from the database, loop over the `$tampiltgl` array that you used to print the dates in the header.

For each date in the `$tampiltgl` array, check if there is an entry in the `$absen` array with the same date. If a match is found, print the status. If no match was found print an empty table cell.

Comment: wahhh amazing answer , thank yuuuuuuu

Comment: what if in the case I add 1 status with a permission description in the permission table sr